# What is the Variance at individual level with a brms model using the binomial family argument?

Tags: vpc, brms

I am using the brms package to define my multilevel model. The outcome is either "0" or "1", therefore I am using as a family argument "binomial()".

In the output of the model I don't find an output about the family specific parameters. The problem is that I need the residual variance for calculating the vpc. And I understood that the estimate of the family specific parameters is the residual variance.

The VPC is calculated like this:
vpc = (Strata Variance/ (Strata Variance + Residual Variance)*100)

So the question is, how can I calculate the vpc and exstract therefore the residual varaince of the model? Thank you so, so much for help!

```
# 3. Perform multilevel analysis to partition the variance between and within intersectional strata for the individual factor modell
model1_individual <- brms::brm(W4_mental_health ~ 1 + BA_life_exspec_integer + BA_scale_emowell + BA_GPA + BA_coping_scale + BA_selfesteem_scale + 
              BA_age + BA_depression_scale + (1|strata),
              data = data_total_NA,
              warmup = 500,
              iter = 1000,
              family = binomial(),
              chains = 1, seed = 195) # Calculate simple intersectional model
model1_individual # Extract variance
```

This is the output:

Family: binomial
Links: mu = logit
Formula: W4_mental_health ~ 1 + BA_life_exspec_integer + BA_scale_emowell + BA_GPA + BA_coping_scale + BA_selfesteem_scale + BA_age + BA_depression_scale + (1 | strata)
Data: data_total_NA (Number of observations: 3203)
Draws: 1 chains, each with iter = 1000; warmup = 500; thin = 1;
total post-warmup draws = 500

Group-Level Effects:
~strata (Number of levels: 16)
Estimate Est.Error l-95% CI u-95% CI Rhat Bulk_ESS Tail_ESS
sd(Intercept)     0.83      0.18     0.52     1.22 1.03      115      223

Population-Level Effects:
Estimate Est.Error l-95% CI u-95% CI Rhat Bulk_ESS Tail_ESS
Intercept                  -0.21      0.95    -2.20     1.58 1.00      277      326
BA_life_exspec_integer2    -0.12      0.52    -1.07     0.96 1.00      239      307
BA_life_exspec_integer3    -0.29      0.50    -1.26     0.70 1.00      237      313
BA_life_exspec_integer4    -0.21      0.50    -1.17     0.78 1.00      235      290
BA_scale_emowell            0.01      0.03    -0.04     0.07 1.01      403      394
BA_GPA                      0.13      0.07     0.00     0.25 1.00      549      439
BA_coping_scale            -0.02      0.02    -0.06     0.03 1.00      656      344
BA_selfesteem_scale        -0.04      0.02    -0.06    -0.01 1.03      628      346
BA_age                     -0.03      0.03    -0.08     0.02 1.00      630      320
BA_depression_scale         0.06      0.02     0.03     0.10 1.00      386      432

Draws were sampled using sampling(NUTS). For each parameter, Bulk_ESS
and Tail_ESS are effective sample size measures, and Rhat is the potential
scale reduction factor on split chains (at convergence, Rhat = 1).